# Customizing the Flask-JWT authenticate function

Tags: python, flask, flask-jwt

In the Flask initalization file, I have

```
app = Flask("myapp")
jwt = JWT(app, AuthController.staff_login, identity)
api.add_resource(StaffLogin, '/login')
```

`StaffLogin` checks for the username / password, and will in turn call `AuthController.staff_login`

```
class AuthController():
    def __init__(self):
        # TODO: Create a config.yaml
        self.engine = create_engine(DefaultConfig.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

        DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = DBSession()                   

    def staff_login(self, staff_name, staff_password):
        result = self.session.query(Staff) # Irrelevant details of query removed
        if Staff_Authentication.check_password(staff_password, query['staff_password']):
                # Build login_response as JSON
                return login_response
```

Now I need a custom login response in this format

```
[
    {
        "projects": [
            {
                "project_id": 1,
                "project_name": "omnipresence",
                "project_root": "/path/to/project/files"
            }
        ],
        "staff_id": 13,
        "staff_name": "adalovelace"
    }
]
```

### Question

How do I get `Flask-JWT` to use my function as `authenticate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flask-JWT is old and has been abandoned. Check out flask-jwt-extended or flask-jwt-simple as alternatives, they are better designed and still maintained (I am the author of those extensions, so I am of course biased).

They are setup so you provide your own endpoint instead of having the extension manage an endpoint for you.

Comment: Pleasant surprise to see you answering @vimalloc :) I have already been using flask-jwt-extended as a workaround. Back to the question, there is no way to customize the token response in flask-jwt then?

Comment: Iirc you can do that by either subclassing and overriding that method or monkey patching Flask-JWT after import, but I don't think there is an easy, built in way otherwise. That said, it has been about a year since I used that library, so I might be remembering incorrectly. The whole extension is a single file, so looking at that may be your best bet. Cheers.

Comment: Also, fwiw, flask-jwt-simple is closer in functionality to flask-jwt then flask-jwt-extended. It isn't opinionated about the contents of the JWT, whereas extended is (you can have complete control over the claims in the JWT: http://flask-jwt-simple.readthedocs.io/en/latest/change_jwt_claims.html). It is a newer, not very well known project atm, but it uses all the battle-tested code that powers flask-jwt-extended. If you are building an application that needs to work with other JWT providers, flask-jwt-simple may be a better bet than flask-jwt-extended (and, imo, flask-jwt). Good luck! :)